# NodeJS create HTTPS Rest body request JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, https, restful-url

i'm trying to do a HTTPS REST request within nodejs using following Code:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');

var postData = {
    'Value1' : 'abc1',
    'Value2' : 'abc2',
    'Value3' : '3'
};
var postBody = querystring.stringify(postData);

var options = {
    host: 'URL'
    port: 443,
    path: 'PATH'
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postBody.length
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.write(postBody);
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

The request works but not as expected. The Body will is not send in JSON Format and Looks like:

> RequestBody":"Value1=abc1&Value2=abc2&Value3=3

The Output should look like that:

> RequestBody":"[\r\n {\r\n \"Value3\": \"3\",\r\n \"Value2\":
>   \"abc2\",\r\n \"Value1\": \"abc1\"\r\n }\r\n]

I think it has something to do with stringify, maybe I have to convert it to JSON Format anyhow..

Answer (score 2):

you need to change content-type.try like this

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');

var postData = {
    'Value1' : 'abc1',
    'Value2' : 'abc2',
    'Value3' : '3'
};
var postBody = postData;

var options = {
    host: 'URL'
    port: 443,
    path: 'PATH'
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.write(postBody);
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Same error as above: TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer

Answer (score 1):

I solved My Problem with the following.

```
jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
    'Value1' : 'abc1',
    'Value2' : 'abc2',
    'Value3' : '3' 
});
var postheaders = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the request's headers is specified the `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. You can try changing this to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Comment: I've just realized that you pass the data as a string. This is not needed, you can just pass an Object.

Comment: If i try this by deleting the stringify command, I'll get following error: TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer